# Load iframe with Fx.Slide effect

Tags: mootools

Could anyone tell my what am I doing wrong? The problem is that i have links that opens in iframe, and I want this iframe to be opened with Slide effect after I click the links (and after content will load to iframe). This is my code:

JS:

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function(){

 var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('slider').hide();

 $$('.cal_titlelink').addEvent('click', function(e) {
         e = new Event(e);
     mySlide.slideIn();
     e.stop();
});
});
```

HTML:

```
    <a class="cal_titlelink" target="details" href="//address is created dynamically by php//">Link 1</a>
    <a class="cal_titlelink" target="details" href="//address is created dynamically by php//">Link 2</a>
....
    <div id="slider"><iframe name="details"></iframe></div>
```

Here you can see how it works http://wisko.pl/ It's a calendar on the left. Slide effect works but iframe is empty. When i remove slider then iframe loads but with no effect. How can i make to load iframe content with slide effect? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZJzjV/114/

```
var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('slider').hide(),
    myFrame = $('myFrame');


$$('.cal_titlelink').addEvent('click', function(e) {

    myFrame.innerHTML = '';

    e = new Event(e);
    mySlide.hide();
    e.stop();

    if (!myFrame.getProperty("src")) {
         myFrame.addEvent("load", function() {
            mySlide.slideIn();
            console.log("loaded");
        });
    }

    myFrame.setProperty('src',this.getProperty('href'));
});
```

this is updated to work by adding a load event once and will slide it in once the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly but i forgot to say that i need this with mootools 1.12 :( This calendar is joomla 1.5 extension. I would be very glad if you could write a first method with 1.12 core. Again, thank you.

Comment: this will work for 1.12 if you replace `.get` with `.getProperty` and `.set` with `.setProperty`

Comment: Thanks again. I have one problem left. I need to reload iframe content after I click second link (I have multiple links in calendar event details) - clicking Link 1 will load iframe content and slide down, clicking Link 2 will slide up iframe, reload content and slide down. http://www.jsfiddle.net/QUJgN/8/

Comment: Is this possible? I have something similar here http://jsfiddle.net/ZJzjV/29/ but i don't know how to make it to wait for iframe load before running slideDown.